# Не импортируется компонент React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть 2 файла. app.jsx и file.jsx которые лежат в одной дериктории.

> app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <h1>Hello</h1>
    }
}

export default App;
```

> file.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from 'app';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

При просмотре в браузере не чего не отображаеться. А когда я скопирую ReactDOM.render(...) в app.jsx все работает. При этом import самого React'а работает. Не пойму в чем проблема.

Answer (score 3):

Импорт вида `import App from 'app';` будет искать библиотеку с названием `app` в `node_modules` или в других местах.

Чтобы импортировать файл лежащий в одной папке, пишем так `import App from './app';` Точка означает текущая директория.